# Google API - Adding API values to properties

Tags: c#, list, properties, indexing, google-api

I'm working with a google api and i need some conversion in order to be able to get the values I want.

When sending a query request to googles api it return a list of strings, like so:

```
//Request to Google API
    Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data.GaData d = r.Execute();

//The property in Gadata used to query Google data 
    public virtual IList<IList<string>> Rows { get; set; }
```

The list "Rows" returns two values, date and visitors. However these two values aren't properties and the result is only the indexers. For example, if I write:

```
//Creating a list where to add dates
List<string> ListVisitors = new List<string>();

//iterates date and visitors and place it into the list
        foreach (var row in d.Rows)
        {
            ListVisitors.Add(row[0]);
            ListVisitors.Add(row[1]);

            Console.WriteLine("Date:" + " " + row[0] + " " + "Visitors:" + " " + row[1]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

As you might expect the result looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Now here is the problem. I would like to use this data (dates and visitors) against another Google API. Problem is in order to do that i need dates and visitors to be properties.

If I make a list like this it would work:

Class:

```
public class GAStatistics
{
    public string Dates { get; set; }
    public string Visitors { get; set; }
}
```

Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<GAStatistics> ListDates = new List<GAStatistics>();

            GAStatistics Date1 = new GAStatistics() { Dates = "20140228", Visitors = "871"};
            GAStatistics Date2 = new GAStatistics() { Dates = "20140227", Visitors = "593" };
            GAStatistics Date3 = new GAStatistics() { Dates = "20140226", Visitors = "553" };

            ListDates.Add(Date1);
            ListDates.Add(Date2);
            ListDates.Add(Date3);

            var Exp = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ListDates.Select(e => string.Format("{0}", e.Dates + "" + "-" + " " + e.Visitors)).ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(Exp);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Here I have two properties that i can use for the other Google API:

[image]

The question is: can I create a class with properties for date and visitors and declare them as the values from rows?

Thank you!

/Chris

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

**Class:**

```
public class GAStatistics
    {

        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Visitors { get; set; }


        public GAStatistics(string _date, string _visitors)
        {

            Date = _date;
            Visitors = _visitors;

        }



    }
```

**Main program:**

Increments GaVisits by populating ListGaVisitors with data from each row in Google Analytics API

```
List<GAStatistics> ListGaVisitors = new List<GAStatistics>();

    foreach (var row in d.Rows)
    {

     GAStatistics GaVisits = new GAStatistics(row[0], row[1]); // This!
     ListGaVisitors.Add(GaVisits);
    }
```

**Result:**

[image]